# In wordpress theme while editing post or page screen option button is not showing

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to edit my post or page in the wordpress. When I go to edit page section, on that page the screen option is not showing at the top. I need to check the custom field. But since screen option is not showing how will I check it and where?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YaEG4.png)

I was expecting that screen option will be available in the top of post edit page.